# How can I to transfer variable from javascript to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following code

```
function insertDataToSurface(i) {

  $("[name=[" + i + "].Height").val('@Model.Sides.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "А").Surfaces.ElementAt(i))');

}
```

error

> Cannot resolve symbol "i"

Comment: Razor is server side code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the client. A javascript variable (`i`) does not even exist at that point.

Comment: You cannot mix javascript looping variables with razor syntax.  The razor in the view is processed before the page is ever sent to the client.  Javascript is only processed client side (after the page has left the server).  That is why you are getting bad symbols when .NET attempts to render the view.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a `JavaScript` function that takes a parameter `i` then you are trying to use it within C# code `@Model.Sides.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "А").Surfaces.ElementAt(i))`. For that latter piece of code to be valid, `i` must exist on the server, not as a parameter to the client function.

Assuming the selection does need to take place on the client, you have a couple of basic options:

1. Send all the `Surfaces` across to the client and use `i` within the function to select the required element of that data,
2. Have the JavaScript call back to the server requesting a partial view containing the data, supplying `i` as the parameter to the URL.